# different states in synchronization

Tags: java

i have two threads thread1 and thread2

**within thread1**

```
synchronized(lock) {  
    lock.wait();  
    if(lock == null)
        {execute1}  
    if(lock != null)  
        {execute2}   
}
```

**within thread2**

```
synchronized(lock) {  
    lock.notify();  
    lock = null;  
}
```

thread1 is called first followed by thread2.
after thread1 calls wait it releases its lock. And thread2 calls notify and sets lock to null.
Now when thread1 tries to acquire lock again why is it not throwing any exception. since lock is set to null and thread1 tries to acquire that lock, shouldn't it throw a null pointer exception when trying acquire the lock.
if it not throwing any exception then thread1 is still reading lock value not null. so shouldn't it execute statements {execute2}?

Comment: Where is `lock` declared? is it an instance variable of the `Runnable`/`Thread` extending class? is it a local variable of the method? we need more details on the code.

Comment: Well, if `lock` was really `null`, your `lock.wait()` would throw an NPE.  In any case, you're synchronizing on `lock`, and then setting it to `null`.  There's no guarantee of visibility on changes to `lock` when this occurs.  You should synchronize on a `final` object.

Comment: lock is an instance variable of type Object in main class A. lock = new Object(); both the threads extends runnable. And i am starting both the threads from the same class A. calling thread1 first and then thread2.

Answer (score 1):

You synchronize on an object, not a variable.  The monitor belongs to the object.

If lock pointed to a non-null object, and then you wait on it, setting `lock` to null doesn't mean a thing, since it was the object *pointed to* by `lock` that was waited on and notified.

Then, execute1 would be called when thread1 regains control since the *variable* is at that point null.

### Edit

Since you seem to be misunderstanding the whole `wait()` and `notify()` semantics, here's a relavent quote from [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> The current thread must own **this object's** monitor. The thread releases ownership of **this monitor** and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on **this object's monitor** to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then **waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor** and resumes execution.

This should show you that the variable is completely irrelevant past being used to point to an *object* that you synchronize/wait/notify.

Comment: if a thread is notified, is it not supposed to acquire a lock again. if it is supposed to acquire a lock what object would it use, would it try to acquire the lock on an object referred to by the variable in the synchronized block (object referred to by lock in synchronized(lock)) or would it try to acquire the the lock on object referred to by the variable at the instant when wait is called like( object referred to by lock when lock.wait() is called)

Comment: @vjk: It obtains the lock again before the call to `wait()` returns control to your method.  The variable is only used to figure out which object to call `wait()` on (just like when you invoke any other instance method!), obviously `wait()` doesn't know about the local variables of your method.  Take a look at the javadoc for [`Object.wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()).